# Does the C# program I created on .NET framework 4.8 use openssl?

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, openssl, schannel

I developed a client that calls Rest API with C# (.NET framework 4.8)

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL);
```

The server's HTTPS certificate encryption suite uses ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256.

I want to know which library my client uses for actual SSL communication.

I just use the HttpWebRequest class of C#.

In this case, do I use the openssl built into the window?

I looked it up and found a module called SChannel in Windows.
I'm not sure if I actually use openssl or channel or anything else.
Does anyone know about this?

It seems that java implements ssl through something called jsse. I searched if there was such a thing in c#.

Comment: Hi. here is a link about ssl in .net. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls
tl;dr: In .NET Framework, the SSL/TLS communication is handled by the SChannel

Answer (score 2):

Here is quote from "[Transport Layer Security (TLS) best practices with the .NET Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls)" from Microsoft:

> Your app's networking goes through Schannel (which is another name for Secure Channel. By configuring Schannel, you can configure your app's behavior.

> The Schannel SSP implements versions of the TLS, DTLS and SSL protocols. Different Windows versions support different protocol versions.

So, `HttpWebRequest` class uses the Windows built-in SChannel security protocol.